# React useEffect Hook not Triggering on First Render with [] Dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-context

I'm getting data via an Axios GET request from a local API and trying to save the data in a Context Object.

**The GET request works properly when I run it outside the Context Provider function.** But when I put it within a UseEffect function with no dependencies - ie. `useEffect( () => /* do something*/, [] )`**the useEffect hook never fires.**

Code here:

```js
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ITEMS } from "./reducers/actions/types";

export const ItemsContext = createContext();

function ItemsContextProvider(props) {
  const [items, dispatch] = useReducer(rootReducer, []);
  
  console.log('this logs');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('this does not');
    axios.get('http://localhost:27015/api/items')
      .then(data => dispatch({type: GET_ITEMS, payload: data}))
  }, [])

  return (
    <ItemsContext.Provider value={{items, dispatch}}>
      { props.children }
    </ItemsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default ItemsContextProvider;
```

**I never see 'this does not' in the console** (double and triple checked). I'm trying to initialise the context to an empty value at first, make the GET request on first render, and then update the context value.

I'd really appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong.

---

**EDIT - Where Context Provider is being rendered**

```js
import React from 'react';
import AppNavbar from "./Components/AppNavbar";
import ShoppingList from "./Components/ShoppingList";
import ItemModal from "./Components/ItemModal";
//IMPORTED HERE (I've checked the import directory is correct)
import ItemsContextProvider from "./ItemsContext"; 
import { Container } from "reactstrap"

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ItemsContextProvider> //RENDERED HERE
      <AppNavbar />
      <Container>
        <ItemModal />
        <ShoppingList /> //CONSUMED HERE
      </Container>
    </ItemsContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have it being consumed in another file that has the following snippet:

```js
const {items, dispatch} = useContext(ItemsContext);
console.log(items, dispatch);
```

I see console logs showing the empty array I initialised outside the useEffect function in the Context Provider and also a reference to the dispatch function.

Comment: Even something like

`useEffect( () => console.log('test'), [] );`

doesn't log anything to console

Comment: Do you see any logs if you console.log outside of useEffect but inside the component?

Comment: Can you post the code where you're rendering `<ItemsContextProvider>`?

Comment: @Mr.Robot Yes. I've updated the snippet in my original post to demonstrate that.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like you have it set up correctly, I would try removing or commenting out the other code until you have it as simple as possible, isolating the problem. Can you make a reproducible version on CodeSandbox?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for quite a while and stumbled upon this thred which did not offer a solution. In my case the data coming from my context did not update after logging in.

I solved it by triggering a rerender after route change by passing in the url as a dependency of the effect. Note that this will always trigger your effect when moving to another page which might or might not be appropriate for your usecase.

In next.js we get access to the pathname by using useRouter. Depending on the framework you use you can adjust your solution. It would look something like this:

```js
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ITEMS } from "./reducers/actions/types";
import { useRouter } from "next/router"; // Import the router

export const ItemsContext = createContext();

function ItemsContextProvider(props) {
  const [items, dispatch] = useReducer(rootReducer, []);
  const router = useRouter(); // using the router

  
  console.log('this logs');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('this does not');
    axios.get('http://localhost:27015/api/items')
      .then(data => dispatch({type: GET_ITEMS, payload: data}))
  }, [router.pathname]) // trigger useEffect on page change

  return (
    <ItemsContext.Provider value={{items, dispatch}}>
      { props.children }
    </ItemsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default ItemsContextProvider;
```

I hope this helps anyone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

`<ItemsContextProvider />` is not being rendered.

Make sure is being consumed and rendered by another jsx parent element.

Comment: I've now posted the code above where it's being rendered in App.js (React imported, so jsx should work). 

Does the context need to be consumed in another file for the code in the Context Provider to work? 

I have it being consumed in another file that has the following snippet: `const {items, dispatch} = useContext(ItemsContext);
  console.log(items, dispatch);`

**I see console logs showing the empty array I initialised outside the useEffect function in the Context Provider and also a reference to the dispatch function.**